# How can I pass optional arguments as optional arguments?

Tags: expl3, optional-arguments, xparse

I have the following environments which are being used in my document.
As you can see, a lot of unnecessary complexity is being added by my arcane optional argument handling using `\IfValueTF`.
Is there a way to simplify this code such that `expl3` 'does what I'm thinking'?
I'd like to be able to express the logic with something like `\begin{displayquote}[#1]`, where `#1` retains its value/no-value status when it's passed to `displayquote`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,csquotes} \ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment { citeverse } { o } {
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\begin{displayquote}[#1]}
    {\begin{displayquote}}
} {
  \end{displayquote}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { citeverse* } { o } {
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\begin{citeverse}[#1]}
    {\begin{citeverse}}

  % make square paragraph
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{.5\textwidth}
} {
  \end{citeverse}
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { pageverse } { o } {
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \null
  \vfill
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\begin{citeverse}[#1]}
    {\begin{citeverse}}
} {
  \end{citeverse}
  \vfill
  \null
}

\NewDocumentEnvironment { pageverse* } { o } {
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\begin{citeverse*}[#1]}
    {\begin{citeverse*}}
} {
  \end{citeverse*}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{citeverse}
Easy come, easy go.
\end{citeverse}

\begin{citeverse}[Winston Churchill]
You have enemies?  Good.
That means you've stood up for something,
  sometime in your life.
\end{citeverse}

\begin{citeverse*}
A bird in the hand beats two in the bush.
In other news, this needs to be made longer
  to really show off the square paragraph functionality.
\end{citeverse*}

\begin{citeverse*}[Benjamin Disraeli]
Action may not always bring happiness;
  but there is no happiness without action.
\end{citeverse*}

\begin{pageverse}
Coming with quotations is hard.
\end{pageverse}

\begin{pageverse}[Abraham Lincoln]
Tact is the ability to describe others as they see themselves.
\end{pageverse}

\begin{pageverse*}
This is supposed to be a really long quotation---one that fills an entire page,
  but I've completely run out of axioms to use!
I can only take comfort in the trend that axioms are short and pithy.
\end{pageverse*}

\begin{pageverse*}[Albert Einstein]
Only one who devotes himself to a cause with
  his whole strength and soul can be a true master.
For this reason mastery demands all of a person.
\end{pageverse*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion you can use the argument specification `O{}` instead of `o`. So you don't need any tests.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That would be a good option in some cases, but I'm not sure about this one.  An empty argument will still produce the citation punctuation with `displayquote`, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't test it with `displayquote`. I thought the environment itself tests whether the argument is empty or not.

Comment: What do you think about: `\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\LetLtxMacro{\citeverse}{\displayquote}
\LetLtxMacro{\endciteverse}{\enddisplayquote}


\NewDocumentEnvironment { citeverse* } { o } {
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\emergencystretch}{.5\textwidth}
  \citeverse
} {
  \endciteverse
}
`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Daisy chaining?  Seems like a good idea to me for this application of the general principle, but if a solution exists for the general case (perhaps you might need to duplicate the optional arguments) that'd be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

You can abstract the construction:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse,csquotes}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineSubEnvironment}{ m m m m m m }
 {
  \NewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { o }
   {
    #3
    \IfValueTF{##1}{\begin{#2}[##1]}{\begin{#2}}
    #4
   }
   {
    #5
    \end{#2}
    #6
   }
 }

\DefineSubEnvironment { citeverse } { displayquote }
  { } % pre begin
  { } % after begin
  { } % pre end
  { } % after end

\DefineSubEnvironment { citeverse*} { citeverse } 
  { } % pre begin 
  {   % after begin
   % make square paragraph
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip}
   \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}
   \setlength{\emergencystretch}{.5\textwidth}
  }
  { } % pre end
  { } % after end

\DefineSubEnvironment { pageverse } { citeverse }
  {   % prebegin
   \clearpage
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \vspace*{\fill}
  }
  { } % after begin
  { } % pre end
  {   % after end
   \vspace*{\fill}
   \clearpage
  }

\DefineSubEnvironment { pageverse* } { citeverse* }
  { } % pre begin
  { } % after begin
  { } % pre end
  { } % after end

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{citeverse}
Easy come, easy go.
\end{citeverse}

\begin{citeverse}[Winston Churchill]
You have enemies?  Good.
That means you've stood up for something,
  sometime in your life.
\end{citeverse}

\begin{citeverse*}
A bird in the hand beats two in the bush.
In other news, this needs to be made longer
  to really show off the square paragraph functionality.
\end{citeverse*}

\begin{citeverse*}[Benjamin Disraeli]
Action may not always bring happiness;
  but there is no happiness without action.
\end{citeverse*}

\begin{pageverse}
Coming with quotations is hard.
\end{pageverse}

\begin{pageverse}[Abraham Lincoln]
Tact is the ability to describe others as they see themselves.
\end{pageverse}

\begin{pageverse*}
This is supposed to be a really long quotation---one that fills an entire page,
  but I've completely run out of axioms to use!
I can only take comfort in the trend that axioms are short and pithy.
\end{pageverse*}

\begin{pageverse*}[Albert Einstein]
Only one who devotes himself to a cause with
  his whole strength and soul can be a true master.
For this reason mastery demands all of a person.
\end{pageverse*}
\end{document}
```