# How to pass xparse optional parameters to other commands, preserving ability to check for `-NoValue-`?

Tags: xparse

I'm running into a situation using xparse where `\IfValueT{#2}{#2}` yields `-NoValue-`.

My `\NewDocumentEnvironment` `poem` `omo` environment is passing its three parameters up to `\NewDocumentCommand`s for further processing. These commands take the `o` parameters as `m` but then test for `-NoValue-` using the usual commands.

But... it's not working as expected. It seems the `-NoValue-` after being passed into a mandatory argument may be seen as just the string "-NoValue-" - leading it to pass the `IfValueT` check. But as far as I can tell, the xparse docs make no mention of such a transformation happening. Perhaps I misunderstand it, but they even seem to contradict that idea: "As the \IfNoValue(TF) tests are expandable, it is possible to test these values later, for example at the point of typesetting or in an expansion context."

What would be the proper way of propagating an optional parameter to other commands for further processing, preserving the ability to check for `-NoValue-`?

---

I've also tried passing the optional parameter up through `o` params, but this seems to bring the same result. I'm pretty sure (though haven't tried) that if I do the check at the top level and omit the optional param entirely when it's originally omitted, then its absence will propagate as expected; but this leads to duplication in the code I'd really like to avoid.

---

I guess this may duplicate this from ten years ago: [How can I pass optional arguments as optional arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142061/how-can-i-pass-optional-arguments-as-optional-arguments)

---

The relevant commands and environments:

```
% 1: title 2: date
\NewDocumentCommand \partialpoemtitleimpl { m m } {%
  #1%
  \IfValueT{#2}{#2}
}

% 1: say 'Poem' 2: title 3: date
\NewDocumentCommand \poemtitleimpl { m m m } {%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{Poem: }%
  \partialpoemtitleimpl{#2}{#3}
}


% *:prepend ``Poem:'' to title in heading and table of contents, 2:examplarline, 3: title, 4:date
\NewDocumentCommand \poemenvstart { s m m m } {%
  \renewcommand*{\section}{
    \flagverse{\Roman{vsection}\addtocounter{vsection}{1}}
  }
  \PoemTitle*{\poemtitleimpl{#1}{#3}{#4}}
%   \section*{\poemtitleimpl{#1}{#3}{#4}}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\poemtitleimpl{#1}{#3}{#4}}
  \addcontentsline{poems}{section}{\partialpoemtitleimpl{#3}{#4}}
  \setcounter{vsection}{1}
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{#2}%
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
  }{%
    \begin{verse}%
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \poemenvend { } {%
  \end{verse}%
}

% 1:examplarline, 2: title, 3:date
\NewDocumentEnvironment{poem}{omo}{%
  \poemenvstart{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}{%
  \poemenvend{}%
}

% Starred environment prepends ``Poem:'' to title in heading and table of contents
% 1:examplarline, 2: title, 3:date
\NewDocumentEnvironment{poem*}{omo}{%
  \poemenvstart*{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}{%
  \poemenvend{}%
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the fragments into a compilable document that people can play with.

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand\frontend{om}{\backend{#1}{#2}}\newcommand\backend[2]{\IfValueT{#1}{Hi, #1, }I'm #2.}\frontend{bored}\frontend[duck]{hungry}` works for me. Please show an example that reproduces your faulty behaviour that we can compile!

Comment: `\IfValueT{#2}` will always return true if `#2` is a `m`andatory argument. Similarly `\ifBooleanT{#1}` is completely out of place.

Comment: As egreg points out, turns out there's a difference between `\newcommand\backend[5] {...}` and `\NewDocumentCommand \backend { m m m m m } { ... }` from `xparse`'s point of view. Which doesn't make sense to me, since I thought `m` was supposed to emulate traditional arguments. But now I know, and can work my code around the fact.

Comment: Though really, it's impractical to use these `IfValueTF` contortions when there's more than one or two optional arguments being forwarded, since you end up with `2^n` if branches. So to get nice argument parsing, I need to use `\NewDocumentCommand`. And to forward optional arguments, I need to use `\newcommand`. But there's seemingly no way to have both.

Comment: Arguments are forwarded. Why do you mention `\newcommand`? It is not in your snippet.

Comment: How and where do you get the error? Since the marker is not text: "It is important to note that `-NoValue-` is constructed such that it will *not* match the simple text input `-NoValue-`, *i.e.* that `\IfNoValueTF{-NoValue-}` will be logically `false`."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. If you forward an unused `o`-argument as is to an `m`-argument of another macro, `\IfValueT` still works as expected for it: `\NewDocumentCommand\foo{om}{\baz{#1}{#2}}\NewDocumentCommand\baz{mm}{\IfValueTF{#1}{This sucks}{#2}}\foo{bar}` prints "bar" and not "This sucks".